# Trying to write a file with a variable in the file name

Tags: ruby

What I have:

```
(Date.new(2013, 01, 01)..Date.new(2013, 01, 03)).each do |date|

    #some code

    File.open('data-date.json', 'w') do |d|  
      d.puts JSON.pretty_generate(employee_final) 
    end

end
```

This generates a file named data-date.json. I need data-20130101.json, for example.

I tried with and without quotes around `date` and `printf '%02d%02d%d', date.month, date.day, date.year` instead of `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (note the double quotes around the string):

```
File.open("data-#{date.strftime('%Y%m%d')}.json", 'w') do |d|
```

Comment: I prefer `File.open(date.strftime("data-%Y%m%d.json"), 'w')` :)